# Get a specific child from children array

Tags: javascript, arrays, children, jquery

I have an array of jQuery `children` which I keep in a variable:

`var panels = panelsHolder.children('div');`

Now, I want to address only one of those children, and I know its index, so I do as follows:

`panels[currentpanel].addClass('show')`

But I get an error, because the object returned by `panels[currentpanel]` isn't a jQuery object, it's a plane DOM element. So I'm forced to convert this to a jQuery object - like this: `jQuery(panels[currentpanel])` - but there must be a way to get that object as a jQuery object from the array.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use [eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) to get jQuery object instead of DOM as you are getting right now.

```
panels.eq(currentpanel).addClass('show')
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when you get the `currentpanel` index from `panels` you're getting the plain DOM object, not the jQuery object. You can fix this by surrounding it with `$()`.

```
$(panels[currentpanel]).addClass('show');
```

**EDIT:** This looks like the quick and dirty way to do it as you need to 'cast' the object to a jQuery object again. [eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) as [Adil](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15475393/1156119) suggests is the way to go.

```
panels.eq(currentpanel).addClass('show')
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `.eq(index).addClass('show')` in jQuery